# XML format does not work with CDATA

Tags: java, xml

I am using following code to format xml string. But it does not work if it has CDATA component inside, otehrwise it works fine. Any ideas?

```
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);
format.setLineWidth(65);
format.setIndenting(true);
format.setIndent(2);
Writer out = new StringWriter();
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);
serializer.serialize(document);
return out.toString();
```

**EDIT** : It does not format the xml below correctly :

```
<named-query name="aaaa">
  <query>
     <![CDATA[ 
        something
     ]]>
  </query>
</named-query>
```

It prints :

```
<named-query name="aaaa">
  <query><![CDATA[
asasasasasasasa
]]></query>
</named-query>
```

Comment: I believe that the second is more correctly formatted, assuming the newlines in the CDATA are because of terminal width

Comment: The second one is the correct formatting for CDATA blocks. The first example is not correct.

Comment: For pretty-printing XML within CDATA, have a look at https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-core

Answer (score 3):

The output looks correct to me:

```
<named-query name="aaaa"> 
  <query><![CDATA[ 
asasasasasasasa 
]]></query> 
</named-query>
```

If the following was generated:

```
<named-query name="aaaa"> 
    <query>
        <![CDATA[ 
            asasasasasasasa 
        ]]>
    </query> 
</named-query>
```

Then you have introduced withspace into the CDATA section, which is actually changing the value.

Comment: Actually it is the other way!